# deserializing with protobuf.net over ria services

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am having problems with de-serializing a collection of objects with ProtoBuf.net. It correctly serializes it in the byte array and I am passing that byte array from a WCF Ria service to Silverlight which is trying to deserialize the results.

I am serializing using `Serializer.Serialize<T>(...)` / `Serializer.Deserialize<T>(...)`, and sending the `byte[]` (via `MemoryStream`) via WCF RIA.

When trying to deserialize in Silverlight, it gives the error:

> Invalid callback signature in ComplexObject.OnDeserializing

Comment: Hard to tell without more code, butit *sounds* like you have a deaeialization callback that is, as suggested, of the wrong signature. Can you clarify, perhaps posting more of the code? If there is a false-positive with an existing RIA callback I'm sure we can work around it. It would help to also clarify the version of protobuf-net you are using.

Comment: Hello Marc, I am using 2.0.0.423. below is the object i am trying to serialize. (there are more properties but i limited it in the sample code)     [ProtoContract()]    
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            
        }

        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public string LastName{ get; set; }
    }



What other code can I give you so you can assist in my troubleshooting?

Comment: This object get filled in the Domain Service and I serialize it prior to sending it the client. Then on the client i try to deserialize it (that's where the error comes in).

Comment: are there any methods involved? Callbacks are usually OnDeserializing etc?

Comment: I have added the methods in the original response. Basically here is my setup. VM calls Domain service which returns the list of users in a byte array serialized by ProtoBuf.net. On the client i deserialize what is sent from the domain service (the server) and try to put it back into a List<Users> which fails. I tried to put the code for serialize/deserialze both on the server for testing and that worked. Is there an issue trying to move it through a domain service?

Comment: I am trying to compress the data sent from the server to the client and then deserialize on the client.

Comment: I'm trying hard to repro this, but I simply can't. Is there any chance you can post the .StackTrace of the exception? At the moment, it *looks* like most likely the glitch here is in the "have been left out". In particular, I'm looking for serialization callbacks, and there are none shown...

Comment: I have edited the original thread with the inner exception and the stacktrace. I appreciate all your help on this Marc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we technically call a "bug", that impacts serialization callbacks with a `SerializationContext` parameter, but only on specific platforms. Basically, a bit of code was the wrong side of a `#if` (to cut binary-formatter related code out of the Silverlight etc builds).

The tests for this have been straightened out, and this is fixed in r431. I've also improved the error message to give a more useful message, including method name (code that already existed elsewhere, but not used from there oddly).

Let me know you need a new zip archive for that (vs build from source).

Annoyingly, the actual "doing" code would have been fine - it was only that sanity-check that was... not sane.

Comment: For info, a callback *without* a parameter would have been fine ;p

Comment: Unfortunately SVN is blocked for us :(. Can you please add the zip archive to the site. Thank you very much for your help on this issue. I will let you know how the testing goes.

Comment: I am now getting: Invalid callback signature in ComplexObject.OnDeserializing. I have updated the main thread with the stack trace/inner exception

Comment: @Pawan  OK, now I'm confused. What is the signature of your `ComplexObject.OnDeserializing` method? I don't need the code - just the signature.

Comment: the actual methods that is deserializing the object is:         public static List<User> DeserializeProtocalBuffer(byte[] buffer)

Comment: @Pawan - yes, but *somewhere* there is a `ComplexObject.OnDeserializing` method, and it is *this* that is causing the burp. If you can let me know the signature, I can check whether this is expected or not. This is the deserialization callback that the error message is referring to.

Comment: (I'm about to disembark to get some sleep, btw)

Comment: AHHH I See!!! The issue was with the generated code that RIA Services makes on the client it auto stubbed out alot of added functionality for the entity. Since it was just a POCO object I marked the class as shared and it works like a charm. Thank you very much for your help with this.

Comment: @Pawan out of curiosity, what was the signature? But yes: shared types will make this order-of-magnitude simpler.

Comment: I actually didn't see a OnDeserializing method in the generated code. There were:
partial void OnCreated();
        partial void OnEntityIdChanging(Guid value);
        partial void OnEntityIdChanged();
        partial void OnNameChanging(string value);
        partial void OnNameChanged();
        partial void OnValueChanging(string value);
        partial void OnValueChanged();

..... And it also inherited from Entity, but that doesn't have a OnDeserializing method.